# factors to consider when checking queries for performance

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am trying to ensure that a DB2 query is written for better performance. Currently I check its execution time on a table for a million records. What other factors should I check/consider to ensure its written in an apt way.

(or)

What is the checklist to evaluate better performance in a DB2 query ? How to measure it ?

Comment: Well, that depends on how you measure "performance"--there are many metrics that could be used. Execution time is a common one for SQL queries. Disk I/O or memory usage could be others.  The best way to check a query for a given criteria is to measure how much of whichever resource (time, disk, memory, etc) it uses, which it sounds like you're doing.  I think you'll need to be more specific if you want a very specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

- [Read and understand the Execution plan](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Sql+tuning/Chapter+3.+Viewing+and+Interpreting+Execution+Plans/).
- Find out which indices are available and which are used.
- Create appropriate indices when needed.
- Consider what columns you REALLY need
- If you work with cursors, find out what tasks should be transfered to another application.

Most important: correct use of indices!